# css print styling

Tags: css, printing, margin

I have a page which displays fine on the screen.

I have a css which then formats the screen for print and re-sizes the sections.

My problem is that the print layout has a margin of approximately an inch from the left of the page which makes 2 elements print off the page on the right hand side.

I could probably compress the contents from the right but I want to know if I can reduce the margin on the left (and basically center the contents)

I have set the body tag on print to `margin:0;` `padding: 0;` but this has no effect?

Is there another setting that controls print margins?

Comment: Yes, but you can't touch it from your web page. Look in the browser's "print settings".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the print margin (and landscape orientation) with CSS like:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: letter landscape;
        margin: 4.0cm;
    }
}
```

And the good news is, it works!  (On Chrome.  [Not supported on other browsers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115199) though I did not test IE9.)

The margin must be in a unit that makes sense in print -- pixels are not allowed.

Chrome will not shrink the margin below a fixed minimum, which may be determined by the printer driver.

Comment: "The margin must be in a unit that makes sense in print -- pixels are not allowed."  This.  ``margin: 0`` wasn't working here.  ``margin: 0in`` does.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to set

`margin:0;` and `padding:0;`

to the `html`, `main content div` and `p` tags

and see if that helps.

Otherwise, your best bet is to set a specific `width` on your elements.