# Can I use CSS to set up different default print page sizes for different pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have a number of pages which I'd like to set up so that printing defaults to A4 landscape in somecases but A3 portrait in others.

Based on the answer in [css print styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086342/css-print-styling) I have tried to set  up the following in a print.less file

```
@media print{

  .print-portrait-a3 {
    @page {
      size: A3 portrait;
      margin: 0.5cm;
    }
  }

  .print-landscape-a4 {
    @page {
      size: A4 landscape;
      margin: 0.5cm;
    }
  }

  .print-portrait-a4 {
    @page {
      size: A4 portrait;
      margin: 0.5cm;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then putting .print-portrait-A3 classes etc at the top of the page sections that I'm printing to try and get them to print to the different page sizes.

However, I can't get this to work - whichever is the last style in my css is the one that gets used by all pages.

I'm only really just beginning with CSS (probably obvious that I don't have much of a clue) so would appreciate some explanation to sort out my misunderstandings.

I'm using jade and bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can nest CSS under a div, just under a media query. 
Here is some untested code adapted from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size-prop:

```
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
 @media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
    @page .print-landscape-a4 {
       margin: 3cm;
       size: A4 landscape;
    }
 }
```

You might also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621368/1584531