# how to fix or design the print window of a browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to fix this printing layout? is there a way?  the text should be aligned left, and the other layout position should be like the original web page,
ive used a javascript which will print only a content from a particular div. but the only problem is this messed up layout.

[image]

Comment: you can define a separate CSS for printing.

Comment: `@print {/* define your styles here */}` or use a separate stylesheet and link to your html document using `media="print"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [css print styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086342/css-print-styling)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a link only answer, but you will need to create a print.css style sheet to specifically style the page when printed. I would suggest looking at the following:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

How you style the page is really up to you, which makes this a slightly broad question. But you simply style the elements using their classes/ids much as you would when styling the screen. Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: _“This is a bit of a link only answer”_ – well, since it was a “picture only”-question to begin with …